# Creating temporary view in Spark sql using org.apache.spark.sql.json OPTIONS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-spark-sql

I have some data in google storage bucket. It is in Json format, originated through Kafka. I want to create a temporary view in spark-sql on top of the bucket.

I tried like this

```
CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW TEMP_1 USING org.apache.spark.sql.json OPTIONS ( path "gs://xxx/xx/");
```

Now, when i try to desc the view name, it only gives me a limited length and does not show all the column names.

```
keys    struct<eventIDs:array<string>,id:string>    NULL
values  struct<Column1:string,columns2:string... 298 more fields>   NULL
```

What should i do, if want to see all the column names in the view? New to spark. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Still looking for an answer, as the below possible solutions did not work for me. I only have access to spark-sql shell. Below answers points to using scala environment which i dont have access to. Please help. Thanks

Comment: You can print the schema using: spark.sql("select * from TEMP_1").printSchema()

Comment: @blackbishop, how do i try this via terminal?

Comment: @jahan go to the terminal that you will find it in the top of your GUI ( dataproc) run spark shell

Comment: @NassereddineBelghith, i am already in spark-sql, when i run the above, it throws me this error :spark-sql> spark.sql("select * from TEMP_1").printSchema();
Error in query: 
mismatched input 'spark' expecting {'(', 'SELECT', 'FROM', 'ADD', 'DESC', 'WITH', 'VALUES', 'CREATE', 'TABLE', 'INSERT', 'DELETE', 'DESCRIBE', 'EXPLAIN', 'SHOW', 'USE', 'DROP', 'ALTER', 'MAP', 'SET', 'RESET', 'START', 'COMMIT', 'ROLLBACK', 'REDUCE', 'REFRESH', 'CLEAR', 'CACHE', 'UNCACHE', 'DFS', 'TRUNCATE', 'ANALYZE', 'LIST', 'REVOKE', 'GRANT', 'LOCK', 'UNLOCK', 'MSCK', 'EXPORT', 'IMPORT', 'LOAD'}(line 1, pos 0)

Comment: @jahan you have an error in the sql request, your spark is working fine so, try to make one space between each term SELECT * FROM

Comment: if it still not working change spark with sc , sc is a reference to the sparkContext

Comment: @NassereddineBelghith, there is already a space between SELECT  *  FROM. I changed  spark to sc, but still no luck. Thank you for responding though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229127/discussion-between-jahan-and-nassereddine-belghith).

Comment: hello : try this query please """SELECT * FROM table_name"""

Answer (score -1):

After some digging, found a solution:

run spark-shell

then

```
scala> val path = "gs://XX/XX/X"
```

```
val df = spark.read.json(path)
```

```
df.printSchema()
```

Worked like a charm.Thank you everyone who chimed in to give the answer. My below average brain took some time to figure it out.

Comment: it is not an answer to your question , you were searching for a temperary view not getting the datafrme schema which is completly different

Comment: None of the solutions above worked for me. The first answer is similar to what i did. so something is better than nothing right.

Comment: no this one is tested by me : hello : try this query please """SELECT * FROM table_name""" you should put the query in """ """